# Downloading Oracle database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) on Linux via wget

Tags: command-line, oracle12c, centos6

How can I download oracle database with wget or curl on CentOS release 6.9 (Final)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oracle supports basic authentication when downloading files.

Try
`wget --http-user=you@domain.com --ask-password "http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle12c/121020/linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2.zip" -O file1of2`

and

`wget --http-user=you@domain.com --ask-password "http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle12c/121020/linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2.zip" -O file2of2`

You'll be prompted for password.

Make sure to verify your downloads.

Comment: The file size 220MB/s??                                                                               2017-10-12 11:07:11 (220 MB/s) - “file1of2” saved [5307/5307]

Comment: I dont know, just verify if the file is a valid .zip first.

Comment: Ok it worked, you are missed AuthParam generete from PC chrome browser.

Comment: @hmzn So how to add AuthParam generete ?

Answer (score 9):

See [Downloading Oracle database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) on Linux via wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705230/downloading-oracle-database-12c-release-1-12-1-0-2-0-on-linux-via-wget)

1. Using your browser on your PC, go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html
2. read, understand and accept license agreement
3. Login with your Oracle SSO Account
4. Start & stop download, copy download link in browser's download manager, for example in Firefox:
   [image]
5. start curl download with copied URL
   `curl "http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle12c/121020/linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2.zip?AuthParam=XXX" -o linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2.zip` (obviously AuthParam=XXX has to be your's)

Comment: where from I get the AuthParam?

Comment: AuthParam can be obtained from step 4

Answer (score 1):

You can download it using wget. But you need **AuthParam** along with the zip URL. You can simply do the same using Internet Explorer. Read the full article here: https://support.dbagenesis.com/knowledge-base/downloading-oracle-12c-using-linux-wget/?unapproved=353&moderation-hash=41dde518defdb8e225ffed9c81fb83da#comment-353